# Using an image as a separator in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use png images as separators in a web page but they don't appear. Am I missing something? And if I had to forgo the images how would you do it instead? Many thanks.

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td align="center">
      <img class="Separator" align="center" style="width:70%" />    
   </td>
</tr>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.Separator {
   background: url('/ct/images/L/Separator.png');
}
```

Comment: You're applying a background to an image tag? Personally I would use a `<hr>` tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Comment: `<img>` requires `src` and are best suited for content, not decoration, use something else. (CSS borders?)

Comment: why don't you just use `src` attribute?

Comment: @Anpher It shouldn't be an image in the first place.

Comment: The bad old days of `spacer.gif` come to mind...

Comment: Oh yes - also OP, in what context are you using a table? Hopefully for tabular data right? and not layout purposes(!)

Comment: `hr` elements come to mind for horizontal separators. Otherwise, you could use a combination of margins, padding, and border styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a regular ol `<hr>` tag will suffice -  **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xP25G/)**

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit........rna, quis interdum orci rutrum quis.</p>

<hr>

<p>Sed mollis urna me............imperdiet ac augue. </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
hr {
    border:0; 
    height:20px; 
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/") 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all suggestions. This one proved simplest

Answer (score 2):

If the separator is merely a horizontal line, you can use the `<hr/>` tag in your HTML.

The purpose of the tag is to separate sections, and it should solve your problem aesthetically  while providing the correct semantic tag (good for SEO and/or screen readers)

It's always important to remember that Google doesn't know what your image is of, but it knows that `<hr/>` is there to mark a separation.

Comment: Interting idea. Would that work in CSS? That's where the image is specified

Comment: No, the hr tag is semantic and is meant to show a break in a section. However, the line that is displayed by the tag can be styled by CSS.  Do you not have access to the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `background` for `img` element... Do it with `div`:

```
.Separator
{
   background: url('/ct/images/L/Separator.png');
   width: 70 % ;
}

...

<div class="Separator"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.separator:after {
    content: url(image.jpg);
}
```