# HTML/CSS Image Divider/Seperator Overlay/Methods?

Tags: html, css, background, divider

I have messed around with CSS examples and HTML enough to create a sleek (in my opinion) website. I have two background images of CSS (section)'s, they both call on elements in my styles.css file to color their background to black and white. However, I want to have an image divider between these two sections.

I looked at articles like 
[Using an image as a separator in HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483026/using-an-image-as-a-separator-in-html-and-css)
that did not help me.

I have tried the <> method and yielded no results, I tried the 
"div class" 
method, and my image showed up! However, it is covered up/overlayed by my two other backgrounds/sections.

How do I put my image so that it is smack middle of the seperation of background colours in my two sections, and how do I make it so my it overlays my two sections/backgrounds?

Let me draw in ASCII art what I would want it to be like..

`WWWWWWWWWWW`   <-- white background / CSS section

`WWWWWWWWWWW`

`OOOOOOOOOOO`   <-- divider image, smack center, overlaying both

`BBBBBBBBBBB`

`BBBBBBBBBBB`   <-- black background / CSS section

Thank you, and if I need to further clarify my question, I would be happy to!

Here is my code for my styles.css

```
.Halloweeny {
        height:100px;
        width: 100 % ;
        background: url('/images/halloween.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        z-index: 99;
}
```

Here is my code from my index.php

```
....

</section>

<div class="Halloweeny"></div>

        <!-- Image section -->
        <section class="image-section red" id="image-section">

.....
```

As you can see, it is between two sections.

Comment: Instead of posting ASCII art, posting the existing code that you have tried (even if it doesn't work) would be much better.

Comment: Alright, edited. Thank you, @Jonathan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your answers got me to do it right, however, Joel Bonet Rodriguez helped me out the most with his snippet of code.

I asked around, and came up with the answer from a buddy of mine, who made a JSFiddle for me to copy from.

https://jsfiddle.net/s7sLujgc/2/

```
 /*   Here is my final code, that works. */
```

CSS:

```
.Halloweeny:before {
        content: "";
        position: relative;
        top: -79.5px;
        display: block;
        height:185px;
        width: 120 % ;
         background: url('/images/halloween.png') center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;  /* <--                        */
         -moz-background-size: cover;   /* <-- I'm not sure these do  */
         -o-background-size: cover;    /* <-- anything at all        */
    }
```

HTML:

```
<section class="image-section red back Halloweeny" id="image section">
```

It seems I just needed to add my Halloweeny to the second section, and add a :before tag to it, and add it in block and a top and a content and all that.

Thanks to all those who helped, +1 Joel, and thanks most to my buddy who helped me out! :)

Answer (score 1):

This must work:

```
.Halloweeny{ 
         height:100px;
         width: 100 % ;
         background: url('/images/halloween.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a div to wrap the 2 section and the image divider and set to position relative

2) Set your class Halloweeny to absolute position, top 0, bottom 0, left 0, right 0, margin auto and z-index 10 should be ok

I think that should do. Not sure if that is want you want.

It's good if you can put your code in codepen or jsfiddle for future questions.